# Error al mostrar página debido a configuración en .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Buen día a todos y gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Al intentar entrar a mi pagina ***ejemplo.com*** que debe ejecutar el archivo default.htm, esto lo hace bien cuando no tengo ningún .htaccess en la raíz de mi página pero cuando agrego el .htaccess ya no me muestra el contenido y muestra este error:

*Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.*

El contenido del archivo .htaccess es el siguiente:

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cfm|cfc|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|html|css|js|gif|cfr|htm)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    Header set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff
</IfModule>
```

Mi duda es porque si permito que se muestren archivos htm no me muestra el contenido y en cambio me surge ese error.

Comment: elimina las 2 primeras lineas ...

Answer (score 0):

Cuando quieres protejer algunos archivos y estructura tienes que comprender que hace cada cosa de tu `.htaccess`

por ejemplo:

```
Order Deny,Allow
```

Indicara el Orden en que se deben aplicar las reglas de denegacion y habilitacion de los recursos.

luego:

```
Deny from all
```

Indica que se debe denegra todos los recursos desde todos los lugares de acceso.

luego:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(php|cfm|cfc|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|html|css|js|gif|cfr|htm)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Le estas diciendo que estos recursos que hagan match deben estar habilitados cosa que extrañamente va a funcionar, si anteriormente estableciste otra regla de denegacion de recursos, en lugar de esto yo ejecutaria algo asi:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes
# Hide the contents of directories
IndexIgnore *
# Hide files of type .png, .zip, .jpg, .gif and .doc from listing
IndexIgnore *.png *.zip *.jpg *.gif *.doc *.pdf *.txt *.jpeg *.log *.map
# Redirect file name with dot at begining
RedirectMatch 403 /\..*$
# Allow access to php files
<Files *.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>
```

de esta manera solo php tendra acceso a los contenido locales.